# Swift CoreData - error in fetching results

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2

I need to have a method that check if a record exists in the Database. **and it needs to be able to run in the background.**
I've followed [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html) to create a method to check if a record exists in DataBase or not. using CoreData of course.
and this is my code sample:

```
private let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
private func checkIfModelExistsByID(id: String, callback: CallbackBool) {
    let privateMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    privateMOC.parentContext = moc
    privateMOC.performBlock {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Groups")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == %@", id)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
        do {
            let results = try privateMOC.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            if results.count > 0 {
                return callback(true)
            }
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
        callback(false)
    }
}
```

### The Problem

when I call the method it says:

> **nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Groups'**

Comment: `moc` doesn't have a parent context or a persistent store. In 'this link' moc is an existing context: 'Our primary context on the main queue'.

Comment: but I don't want to do it in main queue

Comment: `moc` must have either a `persistentStoreCoordinator` or a `parentContext`.